# How to run Hive Map Join when running Hadoop in Windows?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, hadoop-yarn

My metastore is on Derby. I run a simple Map Join query, but it throws an error everytime -

```
ERROR mr.MapredLocalTask: Exception:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:\hadoop-3.2.2\bin\hadoop" (in directory "E:\apache-hive-3.1.2-bin\bin"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask (state=08S01,code=1)
```

Other queries work fine.
Every forum suggests we turn off `hive.auto.convert.join` , and reattempt.
But I don't want to invoke reducers.

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Execute everything in Docker Linux containers, you can find different ready images, for example https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: I do have a running setup of Hive on Windows. Also did try one of these docker containers. But the problem is with running Hive Map Joins. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: You've configured Hive wrong, apparently. It seems it is trying to execute the Linux binaries rather than the `hadoop.cmd` file - based on `is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Had that been the case, I wouldn't have been able to open a hive session. I can run every other query (partitions, ranks, etc.) but not Map Side join. Interestingly this error only comes up during Map Side join

Comment: _wouldn't have been able to open a Hive session_. Not necessarily. You''d be running `hive.cmd` or `beeline.cmd` directly, not something in the `HADOOP_HOME\bin` path